# Delayed_Job - handle_asynchronously with ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

So I'm using Delayed Jobs and I'm trying to figure out how to get all of my mailers to be delayed. Right now, I've put `handle_asynchronously` on all of my action mailer methods… but I don't think that is going to work.

```
def first_notification(time)
  @time = time
  mail :to => time.person.email,
       :from => "email@example.com",
       :subject => "#{time.person.name} wants to say hi"
end
handle_asynchronously :advisor_first_notification, :priority => 20
```

The reason I don't think this is going to work is because I call it as such:

```
UserMailer.first_notification(@time).deliver
```

So how would it handle the `.deliver` part of this? Right now I get an exception.

```
EXCEPTION: #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)>
```

Which makes me feel that something is getting messed up in the deliver aspect.

I would rather not have a separate job file for each email (as I have a lot of them), so what is the proper way to handle this?

The only other option I can think of is to encapsulate the calls into a method within my models and have them have the `handle_asynchronously` - that way they can call the entire thing at once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mailer is a bit tricky... Instead of using the `handle_asynchronously` syntax:

```
UserMailer.delay.first_notification(@time)
```

The 'trick' is having `delay()` before the mailer method

Comment: So then I should be able to do UserMailer.delay.first_notification(@time).deliver? Also, am I able to pass variables into that delay (such as telling it when it needs to be delivered?)

Comment: Yeah this is too bad that ActionMailer is tricky. It would have been a one line upgrade instead of find and replace all `UserMailer` instances with `UserMailer.delay`

Comment: So there is no possibility to tell that every mailer method should be sent asynchronously at once?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger You should ask a new question. This is almost 3 years old.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, still no

Answer (score 4):

Further to Jesse's answer, the [collectiveidea's fork of delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) indicates that you should definitely *not* use the deliver method at all with Rails 3 Mailer code:

```
# without delayed_job
Notifier.signup(@user).deliver
# with delayed_job
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work by doing the following:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_my_mail_method(*args)
    MyMailer.my_mail_method(*args).deliver
  end
  handle_asynchronously :send_my_mail_method

  def my_mail_method(*args)
    # mail call ...
  end
end
```

I like this way because it allows me to test that delivery happens interactively, without having to do something stupid like mock the `delay` call.

Comment: 4.0.6 allows: `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false` &rarr; execute all jobs realtime by disabling delayed jobs (e.g. for testing purposes)